# Flutter BioAuth how to detect user changed bio info

Tags: flutter, dart, biometrics, localauthentication

I'm using package local_auth to do the bio auth in my flutter project, but im facing a issue that when user change the bio info, then app should detect the changes and notify user that the bio info changed, need to use passcode do the authorization. But the authenticate method provided by local_auth package only return a bool, no token or any info.

`flutter: 3.13.0`
`local_auth: 2.1.7`

```
try {
  final bool didAuthenticate = await LocalAuthentication().authenticate(
    localizedReason: 'Please authenticate to show account balance',
    options: const AuthenticationOptions(useErrorDialogs: true),
  );
  debugPrint("didAuthenticate: $didAuthenticate");
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == auth_error.notAvailable) {
  } else if (e.code == auth_error.notEnrolled) {
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

i expect there is a token or something that i can use to compare with when each time user use bio auth to login my app

Comment: Implement the details of generating, storing, and comparing identifiers securely in your application. Ensure compliance with privacy and security standards for handling biometric data.

Comment: Hi Dhruvil, thank u for ur response, but how can i achieve these? cause im using a flutter plugin to do the bio authenticate, if i need to detect the change of user's bio info changes, i need to do it by ios or android ?

Comment: you can use this ```await LocalAuthentication().getAvailableBiometrics();``` in your code.

Comment: yes, i used this method, but it only tells me what are the available biometrics in device, it can't detect the changes of fingerprint or face info. but i have check the github issues, they said there is no way to detect the changes due to security policy over time is out of scope for local_auth. here is the link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88848

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounter this issue, please refer to this package: did_change_authlocal, but for android devices, it only can detect the changes of fingerprint

here is the link of the package:https://pub.dev/packages/did_change_authlocal